# Calculation for Decay of a Pseudoscalar to Two Particles

Tags: quantum-field-theory, half-life

I am following some of the exercises in Srednicki's textbook on QFT.  One of the questions is to consider a theory with a real scalar field $\phi$ and a complex scalar field $\chi$ with

$$L=g \phi \chi^{\dagger} \chi.$$

A fairly long calculation shows that the decay rate of $\phi$ at tree level into a pair of $\chi$ particles is given by

$$\Gamma = \frac{g^2}{16 \pi m_{\phi}} \sqrt{1 - \frac{m_{\chi}^2}{m_{\phi}^2}}.$$

1. I think this result only holds for scalar fields, so would the same calculation go through if instead $\chi$ is a lepton (up to a numerical factor)?
2. Also, what happens to the decay rate if we take a pseudoscalar interaction in the theory like
   $$L = \chi^\dagger g i \gamma^5 \chi \phi~?$$

Comment: In any case, labelling the exact number and page of the problem should help; the formula you give is pathological on several grounds. And how does $\gamma_5$ act on scalars?